# Scale trellis to fit page

Tags: r, lattice

How to I scale a xyplot to fit the whole page?
For example,

```
test=xyplot(conc~uptake|Plant,data=CO2,layout=c(12,1))
trellis.device(pdf,file="test.pdf",paper="a4r")
print(test)
dev.off()
```

You will see that the plot is all squashed to the middle. I wonder if there is a way to let it scale horizontally to fit the page so that it is not as squashed?

(This is an example plot, and making the plot shorter (instead of wider) is not an option in my real plot)

Answer (score 2):

The `paper=` parameter just sets the size of the "canvas" you draw on to. It does not change the `width=` or `height=` parameters of the plot which both default to "7in". So right now you have a 7in square in the middle of an a4 sized page. If you want to fill the page, you'll need to set the width/height

```
test=xyplot(conc~uptake|Plant,data=CO2,layout=c(12,1))
trellis.device(pdf,file="test.pdf",paper="a4r", height=8.3, width=11.7)
print(test)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I am still wondering, is the way to scale it automatically, without knowing the paper size (or the height and width parameters)? A bit like what par(pty="m") does to normal graphics.